# Jenkins - Specific user created job don't get webhook

Tags: jenkins, openshift, jenkins-pipeline

I have a very odd question. I'm running Jenkins on Openshift and want to build and deploy a Github project to a specific project in openshift. I want that when someone updates Github repository that the job is triggered.

Now here comes the odd problem:
I have user A who created Jenkins instance on the Openshift, have owner account on Github on the repository. User A creates a pipelinescript and runs it manually and every step is succeeded.

User B is also owner on the Github Repository and creates Exactly the same pipeline script in Jenkins.

A change is made in Github repository and only User B jenkins job is ran!?!

I've been working on this issue for a long time now. Does anyone had the same problem sometime or can have tips on what could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: How is the pipeline triggered when change is made in Github ? Which plugin are you using ? Polling SCM every few mins ?

Comment: No, GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling. I want it to be triggered when there is an new Commit in Github project.